# is it possible to share session data from a asp.net mvc application and a python application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, django

I would like to be able to share some data between an asp.net mvc application and a python/django application . The type of data I would like to share are authentification or session data.

Answer (score 4):

**This is of course possible** as long as you access some shared resources between both frameworks. There are likely several ways of doing it but one of the most obvious would be using some shared backing store ie. database or maybe even memcached which would be faster. I'm not a Django user but as far as I know memcached is supported in it...

There is of course a more complex scenario related to this and that is **data compatibility**. You will likely have to use some interchangable format that both frameworks understand ie. XML, JSON, BSON or similar. So even when using memcached you will have to do this *translation*.

Comment: Yes that was what i had in mind too. I was actually more interested by a more practical example as my real problem is to share data that IIS/ASP.NET create under the hood (authentification/session for inst). Will it requires to create a module for inst ...

Comment: A better way to share authentication is by using Oauth 2. Google, Facebook, Twitter and lots of Internet companies do auth this way. You would need to implement an oauth provider.

Answer (score 3):

How I would share session...

**Make the Session Cookie sub-domain agnostic**

```
<httpCookies domain=".mydomain.tld" />
```

Have my two sub-domains that I want to share session between

```
www.mydomain.tld [ASP.net MVC app]
extra.mydomain.tld [Python app]
```

**Create a simple web service or generic handler in ASP.net that returns the user's session serialized in JSON or XML.**

If you use generic handler remember to use the IReadOnlySessionState or IRequiresSessionState interfaces on the class.

Now from extra.mydomain.tld you can call your www.mydomain.tld/[Get/Set]SessionValue handler or service. It will pick up on your ".mydomain.tld" cookie and allow sharing modifying values.

Comment: I would like to know where would you put this logic in for asp.net mvc? Would you put in some IIS modules ?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the following approach using a shared database (could be a shared cache or any other datastore):

1. When a user accesses one of your applications at your domain, you create a cookie with the key "_shared_session" and with the value of a random string generated by your application;
2. Save the value of this cookie into the database and relate it to a JSON object holding the data you want to share between applications;
3. When the user accesses the other application, you verify if the cookie with the key "_shared_session" exists and read its value;
4. With the value of the cookie, you can retrieve the shared JSON object.

**Quick answer:** *there should be a filter that look for a shared cookie before creating a new session*

Answer (score 0):

There is an option for storing Session state in MS SQL Server database which is available out of the box. Use the steps from the next kb http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604
It's more about configuration, not implementation.
You can write your own custom storage provider but is there any reason for that?

I'm not familiar with python, but there are at least ODBC drivers for it 
http://wiki.python.org/moin/SQL%20Server